# How to get a list of all page names (with namespaces) of a MediaWiki installation?

Tags: mediawiki

I want to export *all* pages (in *all* namespaces, and with *all* revisions!) of a public MediaWiki installation. I’m just a visitor, so I have no admin access.

The export is possible with the `Special:Export` page. It takes a list of page names and exports all given pages in a single XML file. Great!

However, **how could I get a list of all pages?**

There is `Special:AllPages`. Problems:

- The results are paginated.
- It doesn’t include the namespace in the page name (anchor text).

Is there a better way?

(I know that there may be various special extensions that allow visitors to export pages or download a backup, however, assume that the MediaWiki installation in question doesn’t use any extensions, it’s just a default installation.)

Comment: `Special:AllPages` doesn't include the namespace, because it lists only pages from one namespace at a time. But you might have a better luck with using the API, specifically, [the `allpages` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have no shell access use the WikiTeam [DumpGenerator.py](http://code.google.com/p/wikiteam/wiki/NewTutorial) script. This can do a  XML dump of the current pages or with all their history and also does a dump of all available images along with their descriptions.

Comment: Great tool, thank you! For others interested: as a first step, it creates a text file that contains all page names (incl. namespace), so if someone only needs this, this tool can do it.