# Lock all usernames from imported XML dump

Tags: mediawiki

I’m forking a wiki, therefore I have imported an [XML dump](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/59696/17633) in a fresh MediaWiki installation.

This dump also contains revisions and user pages (in the `User:` namespace), which I want to keep. So there are many links that lead to (existent as well as non-existent) user pages.

However, as I don’t have access to the user database of the original wiki, I have no chance to reserve these usernames for their original owners. So to prevent that someone registers in my wiki with a username that was used in the original wiki (so this new user would automatically own all revisions done by the old user with the same name), I want to **lock all previously used usernames**.

How could I do this?

As there are more than hundred users, I don’t want to solve this manually.

Comment: Do you need help extracting the user names from the XML file, or help figuring out how to reserve the user names once they are extracted (or both)?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Good question. I didn’t think about extracting the usernames from the XML dump, but it totally makes sense to do this (and if having this list, it would allow using [`$wgReservedUsernames`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgReservedUsernames), I guess). So to answer your question: help with both, but for the part about extracting from XML I think it would be sufficient to state in which XML elements/attributes the usernames are specified (but more detailed guidance is welcome, of course). The XML file has a size of ~ 500 MB, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unix tools `grep`, `sed`, `sort`, and `uniq` to pull out all the user names from the dump.

Each users has a page with `<title>User:User Name</title>` in the dump.   You can pull them all out with these commands:

- `grep '<title>User:'` -- Pull out just the titles of the user pages
- `sed 's/.*User://g;s|</title>||g;s/\r//g'` -- Strip it down to just the user name
- `sort` -- alphabetize them
- `uniq` -- remove duplicates (it is a history file)
- `perl -p -e "s/\\n/','/g"`  -- replace the newlines with `','` to make it easy to stick in the `$wgReservedUsernames` array

Putting it all together:

```
grep '<title>User:' my-wiki-dump-history.xml | sed 's/.*User://g;s|</title>||g;s/\r//g' | sort | uniq | perl -p -e "s/\\n/','/g"
```

I tested this by [downloading a dump](https://archive.org/details/southparkshoutwikicom) from archive.org and testing against the included history XML file.  A 500MB file should pose no problems for this method.